# Font Awesome 5 SVG es6 searchPseudoElements

Tags: ecmascript-6, font-awesome-5

trying to use Font Awesome 5 SVG es6 searchPseudoElements

```
import fontawesome from '@fortawesome/fontawesome';
import solid from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid';

fontawesome.library.add(solid.faTrashAlt);
```

works fine with `<span class="fas fa-trash-alt"></span>`

tried adding

```
fontawesome.config = {
    searchPseudoElements: true,
};

:after {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    content:'\f2ed';
}
```

but not rendering, any tips?

Comment: `::after` of which element?

Comment: sass..                 a {
                    display:block;
                    &:after {
      font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
      content:'\f2ed';
     }
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the config before you load the main Font awesome package.

As per docs: ['Order matters' block](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js#pseudo-elements)

```
// Make sure we can use pseudo classes
fontawesome.config = { searchPseudoElements: true };

// Base package
import fontawesome from "@fortawesome/fontawesome";
```

And don't forget to hide your ::after